# Adding URL friendly slugs

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-helper

Currently what i have is

`http://www.example.com/_id`

instead of displaying the generated `id` in the url i want to show the title of my post in the `url`. Such as

`http://www.example.com/this_is_a_new_post`

do i have to add the `slug` field in the collection for this? isn't there any any solution using which i can make a friendly url and i don't have to make another redundant field like `slug`?

P.S. I don't want to use packages. i guess it can be done without packages easily.

Comment: Are you using the iron:router

Comment: yes i am using that for routing

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can do is just to use `/:title`. Iron will automatically decode the title. Firefox handles such URLs pretty nicely. It just converts them, so the user sees the actual title including all special-chars. Also, all the iron helpers are encode the URL string correctly.

To create a slug you can use something like this function:

```
createURLSlug = function (url) {
  var slugRegex = /[^\w\-\.\~]/g
  while(slugRegex.test(url)) {
    url = url.replace(slugRegex, '-')
  }
  return url
}
```

I used the [wiki page on of allowed URL characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#Unreserved) as a reference for this regex.

If you are using [`SimpleSchema`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) you can also use an autoValue:

```
...
  slug: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function () {
      return createURLSlug(this.field('title').value)
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: for this i need to create a `slug` field in collection right? doesn't that make it redundant? and also in router instead of `/:slug` i need to return `/:title`?

Comment: Yes I would create a separate field for it and yes it would be redundant. But you could also call the information inside most caches redundant. Using the `slug` field as a *cache* will spare you running the function every time a route is called. You will need to use `/:slug` as the routes' path.

Comment: i do get an error when i am using this solution. i am using simple schema and autoform. i am getting this error when i try to submit a form. however i tried using the `hooks` in autoform but to no avail.As autoValues are not added by default to autoform i am using  [clean the autovalue](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#normal) from the docs.

Comment: The problem with using `autoForm` hooks is that it isn't very dynamic. If you wanted to use the `somecollection.update` update for example, the hook won't get triggered. What's the error you're getting?

Comment: it is giving a `deny.insert` error and `createURLSlug` is not defined error. its throwing these errors when trying to invoke the insert method from autoform.

Comment: `AutoForms` doesn't create methods for the inserts. So you're gonna have to set up an [`collection.allow`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow) rule. Also the function `createURLSlug` isn't a feature of one of these packages or meteor. It's the one I defined in my answer. So that definition has to be available at the point where SimpleSchema is executed. *I've now tested this approach and it works*

Comment: i know its a custom method. its working now. it was just a typo but now the problem is its not taking the parameter in the template. `{{#pathFor route='jobDetails' slug=this.slug class='collections'}}` previously i was using `linkTo` but i read that it doesn't accept parameters.

Comment: [`pathFor`](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#pathfor) is not a block-helper. This means, that you don't add a hash-sign in front. Also I'd use `{{#pathFor 'jobDetails'}}`. Iron will get the `slug` from the content itself, because it has the same name as the URL parameter. Then finally `pathFor` doesn't accept a class parameter, because it doesn't create an element but returns a `path`.

Comment: ok i get it. but the problem there is its not returning the data associated with that `path` however i was using  `linkTo` before. but i read that `linkTo` doesn't accept parameters. now when i just use this also `{{#pathFor 'jobDetails'}}` it redirects to that but without displaying anything. i am checking on it.